# Cannot see UI in react-native for <TextInput>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, textinput

I am starting with React-Native. I was able to see the `<Text>`. Then I progressed in adding my `<TextInput>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    placeName: ''
  }

  placeNameChangedHandler = event => {
    alert(event)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Ayman</Text>
        <TextInput 
          style={{width:300, borderColor:"black"}}
          value={this.state.placeName}
          onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I am able to bundle my Javascript app, but the UI shows a blank screen.

Note that I'm a novice and I'm using `expo` on my phone for UI device.

Comment: Can you add screenshot what you're getting

Comment: you can try to set `TextInput` value and placeholder an init value.

Answer (score 0):

Add `borderWidth: 1` in `TextInput` styles and it will show the empty textinput.